# Why doesn't stream() work in Scala the way it does in Java? Is there any other API that does the same as stream() API?

Tags: java, scala, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Trying to run the below code in Scala. It returns a *"missing parameter type"* error.

```
def printTree(e: Element, depth: Int){
    System.out.println("Number of children in element : ",e.getChildren().getClass());
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("\t", depth) + e.getText());
    e.getChildren().stream().filter(c=>c instanceOf Element).foreach(c=>printTree((Element)c, depth+1));
}
```

Comment: what is `Element` (fully qualified name?), and what does this have to do with spark?

Comment: In general, `.stream()` whill convert a scala collection to a `Stream`, a special lazy data structure

Comment: `c instanceOf Element` and `(Element)c` aren't valid Scala.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, I changed it to `c instanceOf[Type]` and yet it doesn't work.

Comment: `c.isInstanceOf[Element]` and `c.asInstanceOf[Element]`.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Element is `org.jdom.Element`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov `isInstanceOf` method is executed at runtime, so would it work? Also both the `c.isInstanceOf[Element]` and `c.asInstanceOf[Element]` returned these errors:                                                                                    **Error 1 using `isInstanceOf`** Type mismatch;
found   : Boolean
required: ?0 => Boolean where type ?0                                                         
**Error 2 using `asInstanceOf`** Type mismatch;
found   : org.jdom.Element
required: ?0 => Boolean where type ?0

Answer (score 1):

In Scala you don't need to explicitly work with Java streams. If `e.getCgildren()` return an `Array`, you can omit `.stream()` and the rest will compile.

Comment: Thank you for responding @Andronicus. `e.getChildren()` is a class org.jdom.ContentList$FilterList class type and not an array

Comment: Fixed this issue using: `e.getChildren().filter(c=>c.isInstanceOf[Element]).foreach(c=>printTree(c.asInstanceOf[Element], depth+1))`